# Regular Expression for MM/DD/YYYY in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've just written this regular expression in javaScript however it doesn't seem to work, here's my function:

```
function isGoodDate(dt){
    var reGoodDate = new RegExp("/^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/");
    return reGoodDate.test(dt);
}
```

and this is how I call it in my form validation

```
if(!isGoodDate(userInput[1].value)){
           alert("date not in correct format of MM/dd/YYYY");
           return false;  
        }
```

now I want it to return MM/DD/YYYY however if I put a valid date in it raises the alert? Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Attention, before you copy+paste: The question contains some syntactic errors in its regex. This answer is correcting the syntax. It is not claiming to be the best regex for date/time parsing.**

Try this:

```
function isGoodDate(dt){
    var reGoodDate = /^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/;
    return reGoodDate.test(dt);
}
```

You either declare a regular expression with:

```
new RegExp("^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$")
```

Or:

```
/^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/
```

Notice the `/`

Comment: Something here is off - This returns false if my year is 2050 or greater!

Comment: This answer is about the correct way to declare a regexp. Wether what's in there is correct or not is up to the OP

Comment: thanks for sharing your knowledge it's really helpful for date match case

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Maybe because you are declaring the `isGoodDate()` function, and then you are calling the `isCorrectDate()` function?</strike>

Try:

```
function isGoodDate(dt){
    var reGoodDate = /^(?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/;
    return reGoodDate.test(dt);
}
```

Works like a charm, [test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/5Sfq6/).

Notice, this regex will validate dates from `01/01/1900` through `31/12/2099`. If you want to change the year boundaries, change these numbers `(19|20)` on the last regex block. E.g. If you want the year ranges to be from `01/01/1800` through `31/12/2099`, just change it to `(18|20)`.

Comment: Yeah I nopticed that, have modifed the question that was a typo when trying to reduce my code

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a regular expression for this. Try this:

```
function isGoodDate(dt){
    var dts  = dt.split('/').reverse()
       ,dateTest = new Date(dts.join('/'));
    return isNaN(dateTest) ? false : true;
}

//explained
    var dts  = dt.split('/').reverse()
//      ^ split input and reverse the result
//        ('01/11/2010' becomes [2010,11,01]
//        this way you can make a 'universal' 
//        datestring out of it
       ,dateTest = new Date(dts.join('/'));
//     ^ try converting to a date from the 
//       array just produced, joined by '/'
    return isNaN(dateTest) ? false : true;
//         ^ if the date is invalid, it returns NaN
//           so, if that's the case, return false
```

Comment: It's of course the simplest way, that all can adapt for his purpose. However I wonder if its offer best performance. I guess Date use some kind of regular expression too... It will be interesting to test both

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @KooiInc, but it is not enough to test for NaN

```
function isGoodDate(dt){
    var dts  = dt.split('/').reverse()
       ,dateTest = new Date(dts.join('/'));
    return !isNaN(dateTest) && 
       dateTest.getFullYear()===parseInt(dts[0],10) &&
       dateTest.getMonth()===(parseInt(dts[1],10)-1) &&
       dateTest.getDate()===parseInt(dts[2],10) 
}
```

which will handle 29/2/2001 and 31/4/2011

---

For this script to handle US dates do

```
function isGoodDate(dt){
    var dts  = dt.split('/')
       ,dateTest = new Date(dt);
    return !isNaN(dateTest) && 
       dateTest.getFullYear()===parseInt(dts[2],10) &&
       dateTest.getMonth()===(parseInt(dts[0],10)-1) &&
       dateTest.getDate()===parseInt(dts[1],10) 
}
```

Comment: For the life of me, I can't get this to work for MM/DD/YYYY format. How would you modify it to work that way?

Comment: Completely unsuitable for US dates. Just split without the reverse and create the date with the string as is `new Date(dt)` then yyyy is `parseInt(dts[2],10)` and month is [0] and day is [1]

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your code, it working perfectly fine it here.
click here http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/5Sfq6/

```
function isGoodDate(dt){
var reGoodDate = /^(?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/;
return reGoodDate.test(dt);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Validate (DD-MM-YYYY) format :)

```
function isGoodDate(dt) {
    var reGoodDate = /^(?:(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\-.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\-.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/;
    return reGoodDate.test(dt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code which accepts following date formats:

> MM-DD-YYYY, MM-DD-YY, DD-MM-YYYY, DD-MM-YY, MM/DD/YYYY, MM/DD/YY,
> DD/MM/YYYY, DD/MM/YY, MM\DD\YYYY, MM\DD\YY, DD\MM\YYYY, DD\MM\YY

```
function isGoodDate(dt) {
    var reGoodDate = /(?:((0\d|[12]\d|3[01])|(0\d|1[012]))[\-|\\|\/]((0\d|1[012])|(0\d|[12]\d|3[01]))[\-|\\|\/](((19|20)\d{2})|\d\d))/;
    return reGoodDate.test(dt);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

(/^(0[1-9]|1[012])- /.- /.\d\d$/)
You can use this will work definitely and this is for MM/DD/YYYY