# How to allow date as "00/00/0000" in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have regular expression to validate date in MM/DD/YYYY as below

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])[/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)?\d\d
```

but now I want to allow date should be valid if someone enters 00/00/0000 in this format.

Can any one give me suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for MM/DD/YYY in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402743/regular-expression-for-mm-dd-yyy-in-javascript)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - not a dupe of that question - this one is specifically about adding a "00/00/0000" validation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that's the only addition you want to make to the usual validation:

```
(0?[0-9]|1[012])[/](0?[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0000|(19|20)?\d\d)
```

Or, to be even more exclusive:

```
(00\/00\/0000)|((0?[1-9]|1[012])[/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)?\d\d)
```

Comment: It is accepting 00/00/0000 that is correct, but it is also accepting dates like 00/00/2014, I don't want to accept this kind of date. I want to accept real date in mm/dd/yyyy format as well as 00/00/000.

Comment: I suspect your interface needs rethinking, but so be it. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

If I catch your drift, you want any number allowed, in that case

```
/\d{1,2}\\\d{1,2}\\\d{4}/
```

Looks like your friend.

If that's not the case, and you only want to allow reasonable dates **plus** 00/00/0000, look at [Blazemonger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19184144/871050).

Answer (score 1):

Considering your single exception to the rule it seems like you should keep the solution simple versus continuing to complicate the already complicated regex.

```
/(00\/00\/0000) | ((0?[1-9]|1[012])[/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)?\d\d)/
```