# Using DocuSign REST API to set Data Validation

Tags: docusignapi

I can populate a text field with a date (ex. 12/31/2016) using the REST API. I want to set it so that if a user makes any changes to the text field they must use the same date format.

I've read about setting a `validationPattern` and `validationMessage`, but when I put `<validationPattern>mm/dd/yyyy</validationPattern>` it was more of a literal validation where the field had to be "mm/dd/yyyy".

Is there documentation on how to set the validationPattern with the REST API?

Also, I originally had it so that I set the mask value = date for the text field, but when I tried to populate the field using the REST API it was empty. And I believe I was submitting the correct format (1/1/2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the manual states](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/create-custom-tab.htm?Highlight=validation),

> Javascript RegEx object is used for regular expression validation.

So you need to enter a regular expression. The `mm/dd/yyy` should be presented to your users as *instructions,* it isn't the regexp.

If you want mm/dd/yyyy try [this one from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6402844/64904):

```
^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/rU0pN9/1)

Note: I escaped the literal / by using \/ I don't know offhand if you should escape the regex when entering it via the API or via the browser. I suggest that you test by using the web browser access to DocuSign, then switch to the API.

Comment: @Michael I'm glad it worked for you. Did you need to include the backslash to escape the forward slash in the regex? Thanks.